# Count Users connected in CakePHP Listing

Tags: cakephp, get, find, cakephp-3.x

I have 3 Models (**Adresses**(orders) / **Users** / **Cities**)

and I connect them via adresses_users(*I know adresses is supposed to be with two d´s :/*) and cities_users.

Now I have an action in Adresses Controller which should give me a list for all the cities available and I want a count how many users are in that city (by the cities_users connection.

```
//Get all cities
        $cities = $this->Cities->find('list', [
            'keyField' => 'id',
            'valueField' => function ($cities) {
                return $cities->get('full_info');
            }
            ,'order' => ['name' => 'asc']])
            ->contain(['Users']);
```

I got so far, but I don´t know where I can use the count function for all the containing users. Anyone an idea or documentation link (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs)

Comment: I think you need to retrieve data from cities_users table.why did you do that query in cities table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct query like this,

```
$query = $this->Cities->find();

$query->select(['users_count' => $query->func()->count('Users.id'),
                'city_name' => 'Cities.name']);
$query->leftJoinWith('CitiesUsers');
$query->group('Cities.id');
//debug($query->sql()); debug($query); //to check whether correct sql constructed
//debug($query->toArray());
```

This code is not tested, i wrote it to provide example.